# How Laravel auto load all provider classes from config\app.php => providers

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder how does laravel load all the classes which was registered in **config\app.php**. 
[image]

because I am trying to same thing with another **project**(non laravel framework) where I need to register module class by array. like this

```
class Module {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->register();
        }

        public function register()
        {
            return [
                \Modules\Quiz::class,
                \Modules\Library::class,
                \Modules\Payment::class,
            ];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Providers not for loading classes. Please look up spl_autoload_register on php.net